# Create a new column based on matches in another table, but bring in other columns

Tags: r, dataframe, matching

I have 2 data frames that look something like this (it is a count table). data1 has a column called "Method_Final" that I would like to add into data2. I want to match it based on ONLY columns Method1, Method2, Method3 (the Col1, Col2, Col3, and Count columns don't need to match, but I want them to be brought into the final dataframe). If there is a match on those 3 columns, take the Method_Final from data1 and put it in data2. If there is no match, then make the value "Not Determined". I have an example of what I'm looking for in the data frame below called data_final.

```
data1 <- data.frame("Col1" = c("ABC", "ABC", "EFG", "XYZ"), "Col2" = c("AA", "AA", 
"AA", "BB"),"Col3" = c("Al", "B", "Al", "Al"), "Method1" = 
 c("Sample", "Dry", "Sample", "Sample"), "Method2" = c("Blank", "Not Blank", "Blank", 
"Not Blank"), "Method3" = c("Yes", "Yes", "No", "No"), "Count" = c(1, 4, 6, 2), 
"Method_Final" = c("AAR", "ARG", "PCO", "YRG"))

data2 <- data.frame("Col1" = c("ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "EFG", "XYZ", "XYZ"), "Col2" = 
 c("AA", "AA","CC", "AA", "BB", "CC"), "Col3" = c("Al", "B", "C", "Al", "Al", "C"), 
 "Method1" = c("Sample", "Dry", "Sample", "Sample", "Dry", "Bucket"), "Method2" = 
 c("Blank", "Not Blank", "Blank", "Not Blank", "Not Blank", "Not Blank"), "Method3" = 
 c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes"), "Count" = c(1, 4, 5, 6, 2, 1))
```

I would like to create a new data frame that looks like this with what I described above:

```
data_final <- data.frame("Col1" = c("ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "EFG", "XYZ", "XYZ"), "Col2" 
 = c("AA", "AA","CC", "AA", "BB", "CC"), "Col3" = c("Al", "B", "C", "Al", "Al", "C"), 
 "Method1" = c("Sample", "Dry", "Sample", "Sample", "Dry", "Bucket"), "Method2" = 
c("Blank", "Not Blank", "Blank", "Not Blank", "Not Blank", "Not Blank"), "Method3" = 
c("Yes", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "Yes"), "Count" = c(1, 4, 5, 6, 2, 1), 
"Method_Final" = c("AAR", "ARG", "Not Determined", "YRG", "Not Determined", "Not 
Determined"))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should be possible by:

- left joining data1 into data2 on just Method 1-3 (only these need to match)
- Removing the extra Col 1-3 and count (I just give them the suffix `_remove` and remove them after the joining)
- Replace `NA`s with `Not determined`

Under is an example. Note that I don't get the exact same result as you do in `data_final`, but I believe I have captured the logic you want.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

data2 %>% 
  left_join(
    data1,
    by = c("Method1", "Method2", "Method3"), 
    keep = FALSE, 
    suffix = c("", "_remove")
  ) %>% 
  select(-contains("_remove")) %>% 
  tidyr::replace_na(
    list("Method_Final" = "Not Determined")
  )
#>   Col1 Col2 Col3 Method1   Method2 Method3 Count   Method_Final
#> 1  ABC   AA   Al  Sample     Blank     Yes     1            AAR
#> 2  ABC   AA    B     Dry Not Blank     Yes     4            ARG
#> 3  ABC   CC    C  Sample     Blank     Yes     5            AAR
#> 4  EFG   AA   Al  Sample Not Blank      No     6            YRG
#> 5  XYZ   BB   Al     Dry Not Blank      No     2 Not Determined
#> 6  XYZ   CC    C  Bucket Not Blank     Yes     1 Not Determined
```

Comment: I just realized that in my actual dataset, there are some rows that are in data1 that are not in data2, so this code isn't working performing a left join. Do you have any suggestions on how I can fix my code so it works when there are rows in data1 that are not in data2? Thank you so much :)!

Comment: I see. It would help if you updated your question with this information and some example data to illustrate this. However, you could probably change the `left_join()` to a `full_join()`. This would keep all rows from both datasets. Note that with the code I provided over, Col 1-3 and Count will be NA for rows existing in data1 but not data2 with `full_join()`. You need to add some mutate-logic before the `select(-contains("_remove"))` if you want to keep the values from data1, but not join on these columns.